# Visual Studio 2019 no autocompleta como editor para scripts c# de Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity2d

Estoy creando Scripts c# en Unity, y los edito con visual studio, que es el programa que se abre por defecto para actualizarlos.
Pese a tener las dependencias correctamente, no autocompleta nada de codigo.[image: Imagen Descriptiva]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, ni siquiera marca con colores como suele hacer visual studio normalmente.
He buscao por ahí, y todas las soluciones vienen dadas para proyectos creados en visual studio pero yo no tengo un proyecto, solo un archivo suelto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El IntelliSense (El autocompletado) no te funciona debido a que te figura el Script Unity como "Archivos varios" (Debajo del nombre del script en la pestaña de código).
Podes revisar el siguiente post de StackOverflow (en), donde tiene un detalle completo de las razones y soluciones en cada caso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598927/5228830

Comment: Ese post ya lo he revisado y habla sobre documentos que estan dentro de un proyecto. No me sirve

Comment: @DaniCano faltó decir "gracias por tomarte el tiempo de intentar responder mi pregunta" :)

Comment: Sin ninguna razón aparente, al revisar por tercera vez el paso 2 ha aparecido la opción de Visual Studio y ahora si funciona. Con la opción por defecto se abre visual studio, pero sin archivos de proyecto. Al poner la opcion de visual studio te lo abre con una solución y las .dll necesarias para usar el intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Debes entrar en unity y en edit seleciona: Preferences y luego en external tools selecciona el external script editor el visual studio 2019.
Y luego de ello no te autocompleta es por que en el visual no tienes instalado el unity para ello ve al visual 2019 installer y dale en modificar y luego baja hasta donde esta unity y selecciona y instalalo en donde dice modificar y listo.